# Insert multiple rows with multiple values into database

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert multiple rows into a database where there are multiple values to choose from.

```
foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $name){
    foreach($_POST["txtMaterial"] as $material){
  
          $sQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = :sName AND material = :sMaterial AND size = :sSize GROUP BY id');
          $sQuery->bindValue(':sName', $name);
          $sQuery->bindValue(':sMaterial', $material);
          $sQuery->bindValue(':sSize', $_POST["txtSize"]);
          $sQuery->execute();
          $aOrders = $sQuery->fetchAll();
        
      
          foreach($aOrders as $aOrder){
           
            $sQuery2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, :sUser, :sProduct, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
            $sQuery2->bindValue(':sUser', $_SESSION['jUser']['id']);
            $sQuery2->bindValue(':sProduct', $aOrder['id']);
            $sQuery2->execute();
            
            if($sQuery2->rowCount()){
              session_destroy();
              echo '{"status":1, "message":"success"}';
            }
      
          echo '{"status":0, "message":"error"}';
              
          }
     }
}
```

I have tried this, but it inserts rows with the same name and different materials. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='product'>
    <div class='content'>
        <input name='txtName[]' class='txtName' type='text' value=''>
     </div>
                                  
                                
      <div class='chooseProduct'>
          <div class='attributes'>
              <div class='materials' id='".rand()."'>
                  <div class='text'>Material:</div>
                  <select class='materials-option' name='txtMaterial[]' onChange='getMaterial(this, $(this).parent().siblings());'>
                     <option value='0' selected disabled>Choose material</option> 
                     <option value='".$aMaterial['material_id']."' id='".$aMaterial['material_id']."'>".$aMaterial['material_name']."</option>
                   </select>
               </div>

               <div class='sizes' id='".rand()."'>
                  <div class='text'>Size:</div>
                  <select class='size-option' name='txtSize' onChange='getSize(this);'>
                       <option value='0' selected disabled>Choose size</option>
                       <option value='".$aSize['size_id']."' id='".$aSize['size_id']."'>".$aSize['size_name']."</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone help me out how to insert rows with different name, material and size depending on what's chosen? Thank you.

Comment: _Small Point_ The `<option>` tag does NOT have an `id` attribute

Comment: Is that HTML being output in a loop? I mean is there supposed to be more than one set of what you show us? I ask because I see you doing this `foreach($_POST["txtMaterial"]` and that is not compatible with the HTML you show us because `txtMaterial` is not an array

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was trying some different things, so I deleted it, but it is supposed to be an array

Comment: So there would be Multiple `<div class='product'>` blocks in your real code?

Comment: Seems a little odd having a dropdown with only ONE selectable option in it ???

Comment: Yes, there would

Comment: There are more selectable options taken from the database hence the aMateriel['material_id']

Comment: Should `txtSize` also be an array?

Comment: I haven't tried that because I wanted it to work with materials and name first

Answer (score 0):

I think where we are going here is that there will be one `txtMaterial` for each `txtName`

So the loop inside a loop is not what you want.

Make a single loop, cature the index and then use that index for accessing the other 2 arrays data

```
foreach($_POST["txtName"] as $idx => $name){
  
    // the GROUP BY id in this query seems rather an odd idea
    // specially as id's are normally unique
    $sQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
                            FROM products 
                            WHERE name = :sName 
                            AND material = :sMaterial 
                            AND size = :sSize 
                            GROUP BY id');

    $sQuery->bindValue(':sName', $name);
    $sQuery->bindValue(':sMaterial', $_POST["txtMaterial"][$idx]);
    $sQuery->bindValue(':sSize', $_POST["txtSize"][$idx]);

    $sQuery->execute();

    // Will the above query return more than one row???
    $aOrders = $sQuery->fetchAll();
        
    foreach($aOrders as $aOrder){
           
        $sQuery2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO orders 
                    VALUES (null, :sUser, :sProduct, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');

        $sQuery2->bindValue(':sUser', $_SESSION['jUser']['id']);
        $sQuery2->bindValue(':sProduct', $aOrder['id']);
        
        // INSERT query like UPDATE and DELETE will return either
        // TRUE or FALSE to indicate if the query was successful or not
        $success = $sQuery2->execute();
            
        if($success){
            // no idea why you would want to destroy the session
            // here while you are still in a loop that will want to use it
            // next time round the loop
            //session_destroy();
            echo '{"status":1, "message":"success"}';
        }
      
        // this will run EVERY time round the loop
        // this will just confuse everybody !!!
        echo '{"status":0, "message":"error"}';
              
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to insert only one row with the name, material and size chosen first

Comment: ["txtName"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "ALMAS"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""

Comment: [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "ELVA"
    [27]=>
    string(0) ""
    [28]=>
    string(0) ""
    [29]=>
    string(0) ""
    [30]=>
    string(0) ""
    [31]=>
    string(0) ""
    [32]=>
    string(0) ""
    [33]=>
    string(0) ""
    [34]=>
    string(0) ""

Comment: [35]=>
    string(0) ""
    [36]=>
    string(0) ""
    [37]=>
    string(0) ""
    [38]=>
    string(0) ""
    [39]=>
    string(0) ""
    [40]=>
    string(0) ""
    [41]=>
    string(0) ""
    [42]=>
    string(0) ""
    [43]=>
    string(0) ""
    [44]=>
    string(0) ""
    [45]=>
    string(0) ""
    [46]=>
    string(0) ""
    [47]=>
    string(0) ""
    [48]=>
    string(0) ""
    [49]=>
    string(0) ""
  }

Comment: ["txtMaterial"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["txtSize"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }

Comment: That might have been better in your question ..... But anyway. You have 3 arrays and they are NOT the same size. Is this what you actually expected? 50 and 2 and 2

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, trying my best. I have 50 different names, 3 different materials and 20 different sizes. It returns the two materials that I have chosen and the two sizes I have chosen, but all 50 names empty except the ones chosen